# In pure functional JavaScript: Iterate over a string's characters, and return a value if a condition is met

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, loops

I have a sample function wherein a stream of lower-case letters is input, and if the letters are perfectly consecutive, the function returns `undefined`; but, **if a missing letter broke the continuity**, that **missing letter is returned**.

I'm trying to practice writing more functional/readable code. I'm wondering if the code below can be translated into a more functional form, that is, variables need not be unnecessarily created.

```
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  var splittedStr = str.split('');
  var answer;
  var i = 0;
  var j = 1;
  while (answer === undefined && j < splittedStr.length) {
    var currentLetter = splittedStr[i];
    var nextLetter = splittedStr[j];
    var currentCharCode = currentLetter.charCodeAt(0);
    var nextCharCode = nextLetter.charCodeAt(0);
    if (+nextCharCode - +currentCharCode !== 1) {
      answer = String.fromCharCode(currentCharCode + 1);
    }
    i++;
    j++;
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(missingLetterIs("abcef"));
// -> d
```

Comment: As an aside, `nextCharCode` and `currentCharCode` are already numbers, so you don't need to convert them to numbers in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would simplify your code. I wouldn't consider it more or less "functional" than yours, though:

```
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
    var expected = str.charCodeAt(i-1) + 1;

    if (str.charCodeAt(i) !== expected) {
      return String.fromCharCode(expected);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple functional approach:

```
"abcef"
 .split("")
 .map(a=>a.charCodeAt())
 .filter((a,b,c)=>c[b+1] && a+1!=c[b+1])
 .map(a=>String.fromCharCode(a+1))[0];
```

it yields the missing letter or *undefined* if the set is as-expected.

the advantage of a functional (to me at least) is being able to break a complicated problem down into a series of *discrete* steps.

If I later need to re-use any of those steps, I can give that step's anon function a name, and call it from elsewhere without repetition, whereas you can't recycle the middle of a for-loop.

example: the step `.filter((a,b,c)=>c[b+1] && a+1!=c[b+1])` can become

```
.filter(isBigger)
```

by defining a named function:

```
var isBigger = (a,b,c)=>c[b+1] && a+1!=c[b+1];
```

Comment: So far, this has the best balance of being readable and functional.

Answer (score 2):

Performance wise, a better approach for long strings would be a **dichotomous search** using a recursive function.

```js
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  return recursiveSearch(str, 0, str.length - 1);
}

function recursiveSearch(str, start, end) {
  var sz = end - start;

  return (
    str.charCodeAt(end) - str.charCodeAt(start) == sz ? false : (
    sz == 1 ? String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(start) + 1) : (
    recursiveSearch(str, start, start + (sz >> 1)) ||
    recursiveSearch(str, start + (sz >> 1), end)
  )));
}

console.log(missingLetterIs("abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"));
```

The main idea behind this algorithm is that we can test any sub-string very quickly by computing the difference between the code of its last character and the code of its first character. If all characters are consecutive, it should be equal to the length of the sub-string - 1.

```
'abcdef' : 'f' - 'a' = 5 // => this string is OK
'abdefg' : 'g' - 'a' = 6 // => a letter is missing
```

We start by testing the entire string. If it fails, we repeat the test on the two halves of the string. And so on, recursively, until we find two non-consecutive characters.

**NB**: This method makes the assumption that the input string is indeed missing a character in a continuous sequence. It will fail to detect a problem in a string such as `'abbd'`.

Open the snippet below for a more verbose but more readable version. It includes a log to show the different steps of the process.

```js
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  return recursiveSearch(str, 0, str.length - 1);
}

function recursiveSearch(str, start, end) {
  iter++;

  var sz = end - start,
      res = str.charCodeAt(end) - str.charCodeAt(start) == sz;

  document.getElementById("log").innerHTML +=
    "Testing '" + str.substring(start, end + 1) + "': " +
    (res ? 'passed' : 'failed') + "<br>"
  
  if(res) {
    return false;
  }
  if(sz == 1) {
    return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(start) + 1);
  }
  if((res = recursiveSearch(str, start, start + (sz >> 1))) !== false) {
    return res;
  }
  return recursiveSearch(str, start + (sz >> 1), end);
}

var iter = 0, res = missingLetterIs("abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz");

document.getElementById("log").innerHTML +=
  "<br>The missing letter is '" + res + "'<br>" +
  "Found in " + iter + " iterations";
```

```html
<div id="log" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:13px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  function helper(currentIndex) {
    return (
      str.length < currentIndex + 2
        ? undefined
        : str.charCodeAt(currentIndex) + 1 == str.charCodeAt(currentIndex + 1)
           ? missingLetterIs(str, currentIndex + 1)
           : String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(currentIndex) + 1)
    );
  }

  return helper(0);
}
```

Honestly, I'm not sure this is useful in your case — the `length`-check would probably be clearer as an `if`-block, and the recursion would actually probably be clearer as iteration — but it shows you what you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure functional solution:

```js
// Let's define a generic function that works on numeric sequences:

checkTerm = (seq, term) =>
    !seq.length ? null :
        seq[0] == term ? missingTerm(seq) : 
          term

missingTerm = seq => checkTerm(seq.slice(1), seq[0] + 1)

// (aren't they cute these two)?

console.log(missingTerm([1,2,3,4])) // null
console.log(missingTerm([1,2,4,5])) // 3

// and then apply it to your specific case (strings)

fromCharCode = x => x && String.fromCharCode(x)

missingChar = str => fromCharCode(
    missingTerm([...str].map(x => x.charCodeAt(0)))
)

console.log(missingChar('bcdef')) // null
console.log(missingChar('bcdfg')) // 'e'
```

However, imperative code will be more concise and efficient:

```js
missingChar = str => {
  var n = str[0].charCodeAt(0);
  for (var c of str) {
    var p = String.fromCharCode(n++);
    if (c !== p)
      return p;
  }
}


console.log(missingChar("abcdef"))
console.log(missingChar("abcdfg"))
```

Be warned that `charCodeAt` doesn't work correctly with "astral plane" characters, so something like `missingChar("")` won't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the code points and check if they are consecutive

```
function missingLetterIs(str) {
  var prev = -1;
  for(var character of str) {
    var curr = character.codePointAt(0);
    if(prev >= 0 && curr - prev !== 1)
      return String.fromCodePoint(prev+1);
    prev = curr;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like this;

```js
function getMissingChar(s){
  var mi = Array.prototype.findIndex.call(s,(e,i,a) => i < a.length-1 && a[i+1].charCodeAt(0)-e.charCodeAt(0) !== 1 );
  return mi !== -1 && String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(mi)+1);
}
console.log(getMissingChar("abce"));
```